# Z-index does not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I am working on this site http://www.group---me.my/national/

Please remove --- in the url.

For certain deals, there is options, and when you click on the BuyNow button, a popup comes up. I would like to dim (darken) the background, while the popup is shown.

To do this, on my local test site, I added the following div class:

```
    .overlay{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 333%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 20;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }
```

Then on the Buy Now button, I added

```
    onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';"
```

I also have this in the site

```
    <div id="fade" class="overlay"></div>
```

But the problem is, the overlay always hides all the layers, including the popup, regardless how high I set the popup div's z-index.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show the CSS for the popup directly in the question?

Comment: FYI: All external links on SO are `rel="nofollow"`. Search engines will not follow them. Also, if you don't want search engines to index your site, make an according entry in your `robots.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser? Which version. I am getting it right here. It should hide right?

[image]

And it is prominent. What is that you wanna do here?

Comment: I have actually not uploaded my new codes (with the overlay CSS, etc), because this thing is not working yet. I have the codes on my local.

Comment: No, this is not working right. As you can see in the screen shot. When the popup is shown, I want all stuff to be darkened, only the popup is shown in full opacity. Again, please note that the codes which I posted above is not on the live site.

Comment: @JK - So you want us to guess at what the non-working code looks like? Please add the new code to your question.

Comment: @JK So you say that there is a background modal which is not shown right?

Comment: Give a `position: relative` to the class `black_overlay` instead of `absolute`. It gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't specify some parent element to be relative positioned, your overlay div will be positioned relative to body so it can be above all other content.

Comment: I need more help in this. But I guess it is OK right? The overlay can hide everything (with some opacity), I just need the popup to show in full opacity.

Comment: Can you post your modified code here? Especially the html&css part with your parent block for overlay?